# Loop over Object attributes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to loop over an object's attributes in Rails? I have an object and rather than code up each attribute in the view, I want to output each of them in the view as there are quite a few.

I have an object called `@work_profile` which has many attributes, mainly boolean check box values.

Edit: I see I can use `@work_profile.attributes`. Any help on formatting the hash into something more user friendly would be great.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The [ActiveRecord::Base.attributes()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes) method returns a hash of all the attributes. You can use that to loop over all attributes.

```
@work_profile.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
  ...
end
```

In a view, this would give:

```
<% @work_profile.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value| %>
  <div class="work_profile_attribute">
    <%= attr_name %>: <%= attr_value %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Great that's what I was looking for. How can format the output of the hash in the view?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the output of the hash but I added a code snippet that shows how you could loop over the attributes in a view. Just an example...

Comment: Is there a way to convert the attr_name to something more friendly? Ie: have_a_car: true to something more like Have a car: true

Comment: Try `attr_name.humanize`. This will convert a string such as "have_a_car" into "Have a car". Note that the String#humanize method is provided by Rails so this won't work outside of a Rails environment.