# ActiveRecord attributes reading and writing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, attributes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Imagine we have User model and it has name.
We can simply read and write it:

```
user = User.new
user.name = "Peter Griffin"
user.name #=> "Peter Griffin"
```

Also we can do it via attributes hash (keys are strings):

```
user.attributes["name"] = "Peter Griffin"
user.attributes["name"] #=> "Peter Griffin"
```

And with some other strange hash (keys are symbols this time):

```
user[:name] = "Peter Griffin"
user[:name] #=> "Peter Griffin"
```

What is the difference between this methods? Is there particular cases when we need to use hashes instead of methods? Also I'll be thankful for links to documentation,  because I didn't find good docs on attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found good article about that: http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2011/06/28/5-ways-to-set-attributes-in-activerecord/

Answer (score -2):

If you are using activerecord, using the **first way** should serve you well pretty much 99% of times when you are updating model attribute

Now if you are creating a custom model from scratch without using any activerecord stuff, you'll most likely refer to model attributes through it's hash keys. That's when the **3rd way** you have up there will be of use. Of course, you can modify the custom model to work like the first way.

The **second way** with `attributes` method that returns model attribute hash is useful when you want to refer to all the model hashes. For example, this will this all the model attributes and their values.

```rb
@user.attributes.each do |attr, val|
  puts "#{attr} : #{val}"
end
```

Comment: Yeah I'm using first way 99% of my time. Your answer didn't help me much. Could you provide links to documentation please?

Comment: I can tell your more. When you are overwriting activerecord getters and setters, you should use `read_attribute` and `write_attribute` or attributes hash. Your example of attributes hash isn't practical =(

Comment: There is no functional nor tangible performance difference between all three ways above when you are just working with default Rails activerecord. I gave you two different cases when 2nd and 3rd ways are used. What documentation do you need?

Comment: Documentation where this 3 ways are described. 
> "There is no functional nor tangible performance difference between all three ways above when you are just working with default Rails activerecord"
How can you be sure?

Comment: What exactly were you looking for then? I told you the answer to what you asked. "What is the difference between this methods? Is there particular cases when we need to use hashes instead of methods?"

Comment: I'm looking for more expanded answer to my question.

Comment: I doubt that there is any official document on describing three ways mentioned above. The knowledge of such comes from using Rails long enough.

Comment: "Your example of attributes hash isn't practical". [There are plenty of people who find this approach very practical and useful.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085661/loop-over-object-attributes-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: ok. sorry for that. I just know how to use attributes hash, I was asking examples of difference of usage of three ways

Comment: And if there is no difference why 2nd way uses strings as key, and 3rd way is using symbols? I guess I should dig into active record sources to find answer =)

Comment: BTW there is difference. See my answer